# Zend\Form openTag() method not including all attributes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form2

```
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('customer', array('action' => 'index')));
$form->setAttribute('ng-submit', 'validateForm()');
$form->prepare();
var_dump($form->getAttributes());
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
```

Well, as you can see I'm setting some form attributes ans the dumping them with `var_dump($form->getAttributes());` and here is the result:

```
array (size=4)
    'method' => string 'get' (length=3)
    'name' => string 'searchCustomerForm' (length=18)
    'action' => string '/customer' (length=9)
    'ng-submit' => string 'validateForm()' (length=4)
```

but the result `form` tag is :

```
<form id="searchCustomerForm" action="/customer" name="searchCustomerForm" method="get" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

the ng-submit attribute is missing!!

How Can I set `form` attributes?

Answer (score 1):

`Zend\Form` only allows valid HTML attributes. To get around this you can either use `data-ng-submit` (which is valid in HTML5 at least), or extend the form helper to override either the valid attribute list or skip some elements of the attribute validation.